# SQL / Почему 2 свиду одиновых условия возвращают разные данные

Tags: mysql, sql

Всем доброго времени суток. Сегодня столкнулся с довольно интересной проблемой, решил ее, но все же интересно почему запрос в базу возвращал некоректные условия. 
Вот есть 2 условия выборки:
1.

```
//
WHERE ... and (field1 not like '%value1%' or field2 not like '%value1%') and ...
//
```

2.

```
//
WHERE ... and (field1  or field2 not like '%value1%') and ...
//
```

В чем между ними принципиальная разница, и почему при первом условии мне возвращались данные, которые содержат value1?

Comment: WHERE ... and (field1  or field2 not like '%value1%') and = WHERE ... and ((field1)  or (field2 not like '%value1%')) and.... как то так это читается

Comment: Вы бы полностью привели запрос. Тем не менее, в первом случае срабатывает **OR** - чтобы условие в скобках было *true*, необходимо, чтобы либо *field1*, либо field2 не содержали в себе '%value1%', что у вас и происходит. Во втором случае, разница в том, что вы просто проверяете наличие значения в field1

Comment: @Mr. Brightside , как мне составить условие правильно, чтоб мне вернуло данные, не содержащие в field1 и field2 значения value1?

Comment: WHERE ... and ((field1 not like '%value1%') **and** (field2 not like '%value1%')) and
Скобок жалко чтоли? если надо чтоб и там и там небыло - and, если чтоб не было хоть гдето or

Comment: Ваше первое условие сработает если хотя бы одно из полей не содержит value1. т.е. в выборку не попадут только записи в которых оба поля содержат value1. Если вы хотите что бы в итоге не было записей у которых хотя бы в одном из полей есть value1 замените OR на AND. А второе ваше условие вообще смысла не имеет. SQL разбирается по операторам, по жестким логическим операциям, а не с точки зрения английского языка. И с двух сторон от оператора OR должны стоять выражения, которые можно расценить как ложь или как истину. Выражение "field1" просто проверяет наличие не нулевого значения в field1

Comment: @КонстантинПупкин Вам правильно написал **Владимир Клыков**. В скобке необходимо заменить OR на AND -> "верните мне все значения, где field1 не содержит '%value1%' **И**  field2 не содержит '%value1%'". ну и не лишним будет ознакомиться с [некоторыми](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/and_or.php) [примерами](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp)

Comment: Вмеи большое спасибо!)